# How do I convert Matlab's solve() outcome to decimal?

Tags: matlab, function, formatting

```
syms pmt
PV=(pmt/1.12)*(1-(1/1.12^30));
solve(PV==200000,pmt)
```

Answer given is:

```
1008806316530991104000/4353278821822503
```

but what I want is:

```
231734.827430294
```

P.S.  adding format short/long/whatever doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the `symbolic` output of the `solve`-function into `double`. You can do that using the `double`-function:

```
syms pmt
PV=(pmt/1.12)*(1-(1/1.12^30));
result=solve(PV==200000,pmt);
double(result)
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you:)

Comment: @TalKohavy In that case, consider marking the answer as accepted (tick mark on the upper-left corner)